# How to type hint a vector?

Tags: clojure

How do I type hint by vector in a Clojure function?

```
 (defn foo
   [[^clojure.lang.PersistentVector x]]  
   (prn x))
```

Here I have tried to type hint parameter x. However if I pass in something like `[:foo :bar]` the value of x only appears to be that of `:foo` even when I was expecting `[:foo :bar]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unknowingly destructuring the vector due to double brackets. Take those out:

```
(defn foo
  [^clojure.lang.PersistentVector x]
  (prn x))
```

Comment: When I tried this, I found I was still able to pass a string or array map into the function? I was rather hoping for an exception.

Comment: @Freid001 Type hints are only that -- hints -- to the compiler to help avoid using reflection. They won't prevent you from calling `prn` on something that `prn` will accept.

Comment: @Josh Use the `:pre` check if you need to ensure the data being passed in at runtime. As mentioned above, the hints are purely for the compiler to avoid reflection.